# Python: Splitting a Column into concatenated rows based on specific Values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am sure someone has asked a question like this before but my current attempts to search have not  yielded a solution.

I have a column of text values, for example:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'text':['a','bb','cc','4','m','...']})
print(df2)

  text
0    a
1   bb
2   cc
3    4
4    m
5  ...
```

The column in 'text' is comprised of strings, ints, floats, and nan type data.

I am trying to combine (with a space [' '] between each text value) all the text values *in-between* each number (int/float) in the text column, ignoring Nan values, making each concatenated set a separate row.

What would be the most efficient way to accomplish this?

I thought to possibly read all values into a string, strip the Nan's, then split this successively if a number is encountered, but this seems highly inefficient.

Thank you for your help!

edit:

desired sample output

```
     text
0    'a bb cc'
1    'm ...'
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Comment: udpated with a desired sample output

Comment: What do you want to do with the numbers in the column?

Comment: This operation does not look like a good match for pandas. It is intrinsically sequential. As a side note, can you have two consecutive numbers? If so, what is the expected output? Also, are the numbers by chance equally spaced?

Comment: The numbers can be deleted, i don't need them for my purposes. The numbers are not equally spaced throughout the data. The text values in-between the numbers are actually sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert columns to numeric and test non missing values, so get `True`s for numeric rows, then filter only non numeric in inverted mask by `~` in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and aggregate by cumulative sum with mask by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) with aggregate `join`:

```
#for remove NaNs before solution
df2 = df2.dropna(subset=['text'])

m = pd.to_numeric(df2['text'], errors='coerce').notna()

df = df2.loc[~m, 'text'].groupby(m.cumsum()).agg(' '.join).reset_index(drop=True).to_frame()
print (df)
      text
0  a bb cc
1    m ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid pandas for this operation altogether. Instead, use the library module `more_itertools` - namely, the `split_at()` function:

```
import more_itertools as mit

def test(x): # Test if X is a number of some sort or a nan
    try: float(x); return True
    except: return False

result = [" ".join(x) for x in mit.split_at(df2['text'].dropna(), test)]
# ['a bb cc', 'm ...']
df3 = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['text',])
```

P.S. On a dataframe of 13,000 rows with an average group length of 10, this solution is 2 times faster than the pandas solution proposed by *jezrael* (0.00087 sec vs 0.00156 sec). Not a huge difference, indeed.

Comment: this gives me AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'

Comment: Have you tried the solution _after_ the last edit?

Comment: So, this does seem to run without error now (gives same text results as Jezrael's solution), but in the output dataframe there seem to be large blank spaces (Ex, indices 2-8 are blank and there is text in indicies 1 and 9 in the dataframe)

Comment: I added a feature that removes those blank spaces and also addresses @jezrael's concern about nans.

Comment: to my understanding, the feature you added is the .dropna(). this corrected the issue for most of the blanks but there is still a set of blanks in there. i checked the type and they seem to be of string type. so i am guessing this means these are ' ' strings?

Comment: You may have consecuitive numbers in your data. That would be the only explanation.